# Openflow : Hosts can't ping 100% packet loss - miniedit

Tags: ubuntu, mininet, openflow, opendaylight

I used Miniedit to do this topology :

[image]

These are some results of commands I applied in the Terminal :

```
mininet> net
h8 h8-eth0:s2-eth1
h7 h7-eth0:s2-eth5
h9 h9-eth0:s3-eth3
h5 h5-eth0:s1-eth7
h1 h1-eth0:s1-eth3
h6 h6-eth0:s2-eth4
h3 h3-eth0:s1-eth5
h10 h10-eth0:s3-eth4
h2 h2-eth0:s1-eth4
h4 h4-eth0:s1-eth6
s2 lo:  s2-eth1:h8-eth0 s2-eth2:s1-eth1 s2-eth3:s3-eth1 s2-eth4:h6-eth0 s2-eth5:h7-eth0
s3 lo:  s3-eth1:s2-eth3 s3-eth2:s1-eth2 s3-eth3:h9-eth0 s3-eth4:h10-eth0
s1 lo:  s1-eth1:s2-eth2 s1-eth2:s3-eth2 s1-eth3:h1-eth0 s1-eth4:h2-eth0 s1-eth5:h3-eth0 s1-eth6:h4-eth0 s1-eth7:h5-eth0
c0
mininet>
```

s1 ovs-vsctl list controller

```
mininet> s1 ovs-vsctl list controller
_uuid               : 57eb29e8-7dad-4553-976f-13a9630330de
connection_mode     : []
controller_burst_limit: []
controller_rate_limit: []
enable_async_messages: []
external_ids        : {}
inactivity_probe    : []
is_connected        : true
local_gateway       : []
local_ip            : []
local_netmask       : []
max_backoff         : []
other_config        : {}
role                : other
status              : {sec_since_connect="157", state=ACTIVE}
target              : "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"

_uuid               : f547e8ed-42cc-4c4f-ac77-cd79d5703d9a
connection_mode     : []
controller_burst_limit: []
controller_rate_limit: []
enable_async_messages: []
external_ids        : {}
inactivity_probe    : []
is_connected        : true
local_gateway       : []
local_ip            : []
local_netmask       : []
max_backoff         : []
other_config        : {}
role                : other
status              : {sec_since_connect="157", state=ACTIVE}
target              : "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"

_uuid               : 7da67055-8898-437c-a51e-3f6fa19dc102
connection_mode     : []
controller_burst_limit: []
controller_rate_limit: []
enable_async_messages: []
external_ids        : {}
inactivity_probe    : []
is_connected        : true
local_gateway       : []
local_ip            : []
local_netmask       : []
max_backoff         : []
other_config        : {}
role                : other
status              : {sec_since_connect="157", state=ACTIVE}
target              : "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
mininet>
```

s1 ovs-ofctl show "s1"

```
mininet> s1 ovs-ofctl show "s1"
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:0000000000000001
n_tables:254, n_buffers:256
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
actions: OUTPUT SET_VLAN_VID SET_VLAN_PCP STRIP_VLAN SET_DL_SRC SET_DL_DST SET_NW_SRC SET_NW_DST SET_NW_TOS SET_TP_SRC SET_TP_DST ENQUEUE
 1(s1-eth1): addr:76:1a:b6:a8:6b:e7
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 2(s1-eth2): addr:6a:d8:77:cb:8e:9b
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 3(s1-eth3): addr:3e:4a:6f:b2:fc:c4
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 4(s1-eth4): addr:26:bf:ee:5b:12:30
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 5(s1-eth5): addr:5e:6b:2e:d1:99:93
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 6(s1-eth6): addr:0e:c0:ef:25:01:72
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 7(s1-eth7): addr:be:e2:a5:5f:06:c3
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10GB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10000 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 LOCAL(s1): addr:aa:a0:03:ba:75:44
     config:     PORT_DOWN
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x4): frags=normal miss_send_len=0
mininet>
```

This is the ping between h1 and h2 for example :

```
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 8032ms
pipe 3
mininet>
```

I set an Ip address for each host : h1 : 10.0.0.1, h2 : 10.0.0.2 ...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong about the topology! What makes it not working is the link between S1 and S3. After deleting it, everything is working fine. The spanning tree is not enabled so it is normal that the network between hosts will not be connected.